# VSTO CommandBarButton position

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2003

I'm writing a VSTO add-in to add a button the Standard toolbar for all new MailItems in Outlook 2003.

I've got it mostly finished, but I can't see to work out how to set the button's position on the taskbar - ideally I'd like to place it right next to the Send button.

Here's the code I have so far.

```
Private Sub colInsp_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector) Handles colInsp.NewInspector
    Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim commandBar As Office.CommandBar
    Dim encryptButton As Office.CommandBarButton
    Dim olkitem As Object
    olkitem = Me.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem

    If TypeOf Inspector.CurrentItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        msg = CType(Inspector.CurrentItem, Outlook.MailItem)
        commandBar = Inspector.CommandBars("Standard")
        encryptButton = commandBar.FindControl(Tag:="EncryptMail")
        If Not (encryptButton Is Nothing) Then
            encryptButton.Delete()
        End If
        encryptButton = CType(commandBar.Controls.Add(1), Office.CommandBarButton)
        encryptButton.Style = Office.MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonIconAndCaption
        encryptButton.FaceId = 718
        encryptButton.Caption = "Secure Email"
        encryptButton.Tag = "EncryptMail"
        If olkitem.Sensitivity = Outlook.OlSensitivity.olConfidential Then
            encryptButton.State = Office.MsoButtonState.msoButtonDown
        End If
        AddHandler encryptButton.Click, AddressOf encryptButton_Click
        msg = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help would be tremendously appreciated!

Thanks,
Jim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have used the `commandBar.AddControl(control, position)` syntax instead